# How to check if there is a space in an input line in C++

Tags: for-loop, c++11, input

I am trying to check if there is a space in an input line.

I have indexed the input but I got an error: "Expected ';' expected ')' "

```
string mike20;
int count = 0;

while (getline(cin, mike20))


for (mike20[0]); (isspace(mike20[0]); ++mike20[0])


return 0;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly they are syntax error in your code, it is more like that `for (mike20[0]; isspace(mike20[0]); ++mike20[0])`. Secondly you seem don't understand how the for loop work. As is nothing change, so the loop is infinite.
You need a variable to browse each char of the string and do your test on each of them.

```
int cursor;
for (cursor = 0; cursor < number_of_char_in_mike20; ++cursor)
{
    isspace(mike20[i]);
}
```

this code is incomplet you need to declare and initialise the `number_of_char_in_mike20` variable and the isspace() function must be define if is not.

PS: don't forget braces {} for while loop and for loop, without only the first instruction is repeated.

```
for (initialisation(only once); test(each time); increment(each time))
    first_instruction; // each time
    second_instruction; // after the loop end
    third_instruction; // after the loop end
fourth_instruction; // after the loop end
fifth_instruction; // after the loop end

for (initialisation(only once); test(each time); increment(each time))
{
    first_instruction; // each time
    second_instruction; // each time
    third_instruction; // each time
}
fourth_instruction; // after the loop end
fifth_instruction; // after the loop end
```

Comment: Thanks! I have checked your suggestions!